(MissingPluginException) in unit test for Flutter using Path Provider and Hive
I'am tryng to run my unit test for this project, and it's giving me this error message:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 332:7  MethodChannel._invokeMethod
LateInitializationError: Field 'todoBox' has not been initialized.
test\unit_test\todo_unit_test.dart        todoBox
test\unit_test\todo_unit_test.dart 35:13  main.<fn>

How can I solve this error?
**
Here is the code:
**
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/src/modules/adapter/todo_adapter.dart';

late TodoItemMock todoItemMock;
late Box<TodoItemMock> todoBox;

class TodoItemMock extends Mock implements TodoItem {}


class HiveConfig {
  static start() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);
  }
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setUp(
    () async {
      await HiveConfig.start();
      Hive.registerAdapter(TodoItemAdapter());
      todoBox = await Hive.openBox<TodoItemMock>('todoBox');
    },
  );

  tearDownAll(
    () async {
      await todoBox.close();
    },
  );

  test('Get no results from the Box', () async {
    expect(todoBox.get(0), completion(findsNothing));
  });
}

I tried to make a Mock for the path provider but it's not possible to call the class to mock it

Maybe move declarations of todoBox and todoItemMock in to main?

Hi, I read your suggestion, and sadly it not work, the error is in the path_provider. But thanks for your answer!!

Instead of mocking the path_provider try to mock the method channel that the path_provider wants to access.
Before the test set:
  TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
  .setMockMethodCallHandler(
const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/path_provider'),
(MethodCall methodCall) async => 'test',);


this should be marked as accepted answer
